# color chooser (color palette) showing all colors

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i would like to have an image like this one on my form.

http://www.asptemplate.net/colorpalettegenerator/screenshot1.jpg

depending on where the user clicks, i would like the background of the form to turn this color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ColorPicker's on codeproject. [One example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ColorPickerControl.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

An [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx) went into it in detail.